# AutoCompleteTextView with OnKeyListener

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, textview, keylistener

I have a `AutoCompleteTextView` and I have set `OnItemClick`, but now I want to set `OnKeyListener` for search button. I have searched but haven't found anything to help me out.

Here's my auto complete xml:

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView 
                android:id="@+id/autocomplete_stores" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="60dp" 
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:hint="Stores Search:" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch" />
```

And the java code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView searchStores;
String[] searchStoresString; 
ArrayAdapter<String> searchStoresAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stores);

    findviews();
    autocomplete();

    searchStores.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
{ 
    String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, str + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void findviews()
{
    searchStores = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_stores);
}

private void autocomplete()
{
    searchStoresString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stores_array);
    searchStoresAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, searchStoresString);

    searchStores.setThreshold(1); 
    searchStores.setAdapter(searchStoresAdapter);
}
```

Everything is working fine. Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as for setting [setKeyListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) for AutoCompleteTextView :

```
edtTitle = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edtTitle);
        edtTitle.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(Current_Activity.this, arg1+"",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // return true; - if consumed
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: or you can als use setOnEditorActionListener for AutoCompleteTextView for getting EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH action

Comment: What's the difference between KeyListener and EditorListener?

Comment: @RotaryHeary : i think EditorListener i for EditView so try by using KeyListener

Comment: Not working here. For some reason the listener never fires. By the way, you have a (brakets) syntax error.

Comment: Yeah, neither of these event listeners fire. I don't see why the OP marked this solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you try `setKeyListener()` ?? for more [help](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)

Comment: Yes but got error, have tryed a few ways. I just don't know how to do it with AutoCompleteTextView